# Why the cast give a rvalue in C?

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I have a question about `lvalue` and `rvalue`:

```
void * p;

typedef struct
{
  int a;
  int b;
} TypeA;

&(TypeA*)p; // here it complains lvalue required as unary '&' operand
```

why the `(TypeA*)p` gives a rvaule?

Comment: You aren't doing anything with it.  What would be the purpose of that statement?

Comment: cast it to different type

Comment: You can't change a type.  You need something like:  TypeA A = &(TypeA*)p;
You need to assign the cast to something.

Comment: Ok, but it complains lvalue required as unary '&' operand, and the purpose is to ask why (TypeA*)p gives a rvaule

Comment: You can drop the cast alltogether. Just write `&p`, this gives you the address of the memory location where the `p` pointer is stored.

Comment: @Jim: yes it compiles. `&p ;` is a valid statement, even if it does nothing, just as e.g. `123 ;` is a valid statement that does nothing either.

Answer (score 4):

`p` is an object of type "pointer to `void`"; if you cast the value in `p` to type "pointer to `TypeA`" you no longer have an *'object'*: you have just a *'value'*.

*'Values'* (like `42`) have no address.

```
/* wrong code; this does not work */
int *p = &42;            /* values do not */
void *q = &(0xDEADBEEF); /* have addresses */
```

Comment: @ratzip `TypeA*` is a _type_. `p` is a pointer (and an lvalue). `(TypeA*)p` is a pointer (and an rvalue).

Answer (score 2):

Casting returns r-value and unary `&` needs a l-value as its operand.

#### [Address-of Operator: &](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64sa8b1e.aspx)

> The operand of the address-of operator can be either a function designator or an **l-value** that designates an object that is not a bit field and is not declared with the `register` storage-class specifier.

Answer (score 0):

```
(TypeA*)p
```

This statement is going to type cast and return a value that needs to be assigned to a variable. so you can not directly use `&` on it since the return is a value which will not have a adress.